# How to prove something is a subset using only the subspace test and abstract properties of dot products?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is if $v_0\in\Bbb R^n$ is a fixed vector and we define $W\subset\Bbb R^n$ to be the set of all vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ that are orthogonal to the particular vector $v_0$. In set builder notation it would be $W=\{w\in\Bbb R^n:w\cdot v_0=0\}$. (the dot represents the dot product). Then using the subspace test, and abstract properties of dot products how does one prove that $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$?

Note: To use abstract properties means you should not use the formula for a dot product. Instead, use properties, such as the distributive property, in abstract form: a.(b+c) = a.b + a.c (there are probably more properties that you would need to use). Also, make sure you use the particular fixed vector v0 as you work through your proof.

Answer (score 1):

First, your definition of $W$ is not correct. You have

$$W = \{w \in \mathbb R^n \mid w \cdot v_0=0 \}$$ (you missed the $=0$ part).

Then the dot product is bilinear. So if $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $w, w_1,w_2 \in W$ with $ w_1 \cdot v_0= w_2 \cdot v_0=0$ you get

$$(w_1+w_2) \cdot v_0 = w_1 \cdot v_0 + w_2 \cdot v_0=0$$ and

$$(\lambda w) \cdot v_0 = \lambda (w \cdot v_0) = 0.$$

Proving that $W$ is a linear subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Well, check whether $w\in W$ and $c\in\Bbb R\implies cw\in W$.  Since $cw\cdot v_0=c(w\cdot v_0)=c\cdot0=0$, it's yes.

Secondly, if $w,v\in W$ do we have $w+v\in W$?  Well, $(w+v)\cdot v_0=w\cdot v_0+v\cdot v_0=0+0=0$.  So yes.

Thus it's a subspace.